# AbstractRegionPainter Java 7 dynamic import

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

As you know [nimbus package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/enhancements-7.html) is change in java 7. I am using AbstractRegionPainter with java6 in my app's server side, and my app's client side must work both in java 6 and 7. So how can i import this abstract class dynamicly depends on client's java version. The import text must change belong to java version. Or another solution i must extend it dynamicly belong to java version.

Comment: import for Nimbus was changed from com.sun.java.swing (Java6) to standard import in Java7, please where is problem

Comment: my application is a client-server swing app. I want compile my code in java 6, but when a java7 client run it, interface is not draw correctly.