# Java inheritance; extends from a changeable type

Tags: java, oop

Can I create a subclass which parent is dynamic? For example; on `class A extends B` code,  can I change `B` according to a condition? If can I return it from a method what will be the method's return type? I mean `class A extends getClassAccToCondition()` return type.

Comment: Have you looked at generics in java?

Comment: You can't dynamically define super classes at run time, they have to be explicitly defined. What are your reasons for doing this maybe there is another option.

Comment: it is about this problem; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399843/abstractregionpainter-java-7-dynamic-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to use a way like a variation of simple polymorphism with Factory pattern. It will work for me i think. Thanks for answers.

```
public class Main {
    public static I getClassBelongToCondition(boolean Condition) {
        if (Condition) {
            return new A();
        } else {
            return new C();
        }
    }

}

interface I {
}

class A extends B implements I {
}

class C extends D implements I {
}

class B {
}

class D {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already say this is not possible.

For this kind of problem you could use the factory pattern. If you have a 
class hierarchy like this:

```
class SuperType { ... }
class SubType1 extends SuperType {...}
class SubType2 extends SuperType {...}
```

You could have a factory like this:

```
class Factory {
  public static SuperType create (Condition cond) {
    if(cond.matchForType1())
      return new SubType1();
    else
      return new SubType2();
  }
}
```

You can than call this method via `Factory.create(<condition that match for the required type>)`.

If you search for "factory pattern" + "java" you will find a lot of
better examples.

Comment: But in my case 'SuperType' is changable. What will the create method's return type?

Comment: SubType1 and SubType2 are different implementations of SuperType. The returned type is 'SuperType', so depending on your condition you will get the respective implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No, the class that you are extending has to be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, its not possible to achieve this in java. However, I would like to try and solve actual business problem using polymorphism and some sort of factory method pattern. Not sure, if this is helpful to you but varying parent is not achievable in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define a class that is not statically typed at compile time.
However, you can generate classes at runtime, take a look at [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). That being said, code generation is not the only option. If you don't need a dynamic *superclass* but only an *interface*, you can use [dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html).